# My-SQL inserting Date in format '17-DEC-80'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

How can we insert date in in '17-DEC-80' format ?
How to find the last day of this month ?
like this I want to insert 10 dates in the given format and find the last day of the months specified in the date.

Comment: You asked multiple questions. Please consider changing to one question. Dates are stored in a specific formats in MySQL; Convert to that format on insert, and then convert back upon retrieval.

Comment: Seconding @EdHayes3 comment, and this should help you with the rest https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

This can be acheived through the STR_TO_DATE and DATE_FORMAT internal functions.

You can insert a date so long as you accompany it with the format you are providing it in.

```
INSERT INTO DateFormats (DF_DATE_FIELD) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('17-Dec-80', '%d-%b-%y'));
```

You can also SELECT a that same format date value with the DATE_FORMAT() function. To return the value you want from the table you would use

```
SELECT 
    DF_ID, 
    DF_DATE_FIELD,  
    DATE_FORMAT(DF_DATE_FIELD, '%d-%b-%y')
FROM DateFormats;
```

Assuming that DF_DATE_FIELD is in fact a DATE or DATETIME field. Also beware that this is case sensitive

The formatting is as follows

```
%d = Day of Month for 2 places (i.e 05, 12, 23)
%b = Abbreviated Month (i.e JAN, FEB, DEC)
%y = 2 digit year code (i.e 18, 80, 99)
```

Read more about formatting [At this handy W3 Schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

And use [this DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cAhQDtE3p3Mk6eyBuXt9b5/0) for reference

Answer (score 1):

To follow your desired format, use below;

```
select STR_TO_DATE('17-Dec-80', '%d-%b-%y');
```

To get last day of the month

```
select LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE('17-Dec-80', '%d-%b-%y'));
```